# how can i open a file from specific folder of server to browser in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I'm doing a web application where I can upload and download pdf files from server.

In this I created a pdf files and stored its path on the database.

What I want is when I search by some criteria (like filename) I should get list of files from db. When I click open link it should be opened in jsp.

Downloading part was done by me.  What I need is just to open a pdf in jsp.

is it possible to open server file from jsp?

Comment: JSP is a normal HTML file at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Place those files outside `WEB-INF` folder and access. WEB-INF folder is secure in a Java EE environment. By placing your files inside the `WebContent` folder and outside the WEB-INF folder will help you to access those files for download. You need to mention the full path for that file. E.g for an image your path will be `https://localhost:9444/AppName/resources/theme/images/logo.png`